# Difference between Application Trace and Framework Trace

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails. I want to know about the purpose of **Application Trace** and **Framework Trace** which are always shown if there is any error in our Rails application. So many developers while asking their question always post these traces to debug their problem. How these traces are helpful in order to debug our Errors in Rails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between the two? Or how can they both be used for debugging? These are two different questions.

Comment: In rails you see both at the same time. The app lication trace will tell you how your code is failing. Framework will will give you s lot more info and you can sometimes ignore it. For example if you see an error coming from a controller method the framework trace will tell you that it has gone through url parsing, routing, etc. That's what lead to the problem even though that's not where the problem is directly found. Honestly using trace to debug errors is just practice. You'll learn to recognize common errors. Using a debugger like pry is also immensely helpful.

Comment: I need both difference and how they can be used